# Analyzing memory with MAT - question about UTF characters

Tags: java, memory, utf-8, duplicates, analysis

I get an .hprof file and I'm analyzing it with Eclipse Memory Analyser (MAT).

I run *Top Component* report and, in *Duplicate Strings* section, MAT detects some String instances with identical content.

I'm working with `String.intern()` and other homework for me, but now this is not my question.
That report shows me duplicated Strings like these:

- \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000....
- \u000a\u0009\u0009
- \u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009 
  And so on.

Other Strings are readable, but, how about these ones? I'm thinking they are from XML parsing (I use JibX in my app).

My questions are:

- What do you think these strings are coming? How can I analyse them better?
- If they are from XML parsing or something else, how can I clean/clear them after parsing? Maybe is JibX 1.0.1 Release too old for these issues?

Any suggestion about these *UTF-8 like* Strings would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the suspicious String and select List Objects/With Incoming References. This will show you the objects that reference your Strings.

[image: incoming references]

Comment: Thanks. This has been very helpful for me. I get the origin of these Strings! They come from reading XML files with Apache Commons Configuration. After reading and getting parameters from the file, I have done _.close()_ and it works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to see Strings with many \u0000 characters, which is very uncommon given the fact that Strings are not 0-terminated in Java, so they are created from a String(byte[]) constructor, maybe a String(byte[],encoding) constructor, from byte arrays containing 0s.

I would use a profiler and analyse the call graphs of these constructors. Then you will find the culprit.

Comment: +1 - good theory ... the corollary being that there may be a bug that is causing your application to turn uninitialized byte array contents into strings.